# XPath select image links - parent href link of img src only if it exists, else select img src link

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I ran into a somewhat complicated XPath problem. Consider this HTML of part of a web page (I used Imgur and replaced some text):

```
<a href="//i.imgur.com/ahreflink.jpg" class="zoom">
    <img class="post-image-placeholder" src="//i.imgur.com/imgsrclink.jpg">
    </img>
</a>
```

I first want to search all `img` tags in the document and finding their corresponding `src`es. Next, I want to check if the `img src` link contains an image file extension (.jpeg, .jpg, .gif, .png). If it doesn't contain an image extension, don't grab it. In this case it has an image extension. Now we want to figure out which link we want to grab. Since the `parent href` exists, we should grab the corresponding link.

Desired Result: `//i.imgur.com/ahreflink.jpg`

But now let's say the `parent href` doesn't exist:

```
<a name="missing! oh no!">
    <img class="post-image-placeholder" src="//i.imgur.com/imgsrclink.jpg">
    </img>
</a>
```

Desired Result: `//i.imgur.com/imgsrclink.jpg`

How do I go about constructing this XPath? If it helps, I am also using Python (Scrapy) with XPath. So if the problem needs to be separated out, Python can be used as well.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I've only gotten to the part where I check for image extensions of links, but confused about how to select which link to grab.

Comment: Do you want to try and achieve the result entirely using XPath or do you have a scripting language you're using that you can implement some of the logic with?

Comment: Whichever can yield a cleaner and more efficient solution. I'm using python.

Comment: I've added that to your tags. I don't know python, good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very simple to do in a single xpath expression:

```
//a[not(@href)]/img/@src | //a[img]/@href
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought of prioritizing the img src first (with not) since logically speaking we're prioritizing the href first. Looks like a promising solution, though I'd have to test it out first.

Comment: @dtgee There's no priority, only filters.

Answer (score 4):

*You don't have to do it in a single XPath expression*. Here is a Scrapy specific implementation omitting the image extension check (judging by the comments, you've already figured that out):

```
images = response.xpath("//a/img")
for image in images:
    a_link = image.xpath("../@href").extract_first()
    image_link = image.xpath("@src").extract_first()

    print(a_link or image_link)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I guess I got stuck in a trance thinking I had to use XPath only for selecting everything. I shall learn from this mistake!

Comment: @dtgee You probably *do* want to do it in xpath though, to keep the heavy lifting in C rather than Python.

Comment: True. Using Python makes the code much more readable, but I guess using XPath and adding some comments would serve the same purpose.